# Using a table-responsive in a repeat control need ffixed column widths

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

I have created a table-responsive in a repeat control and calculate the contents of the rows and columns which all works fine. The problem is that each table has different column widths (see the image below). Is there a way to set the column widths so that they would be equal in all iterations of the repeat. The column widths do not appear to be related to the width of the data displayed and the first column seems to be growing with each iteration.
I guess one fix?? would be to pad them out with spaces to some fixed length.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities:

- Build the whole result in one big table and use colspan (for APC) and rowspan (for the countries/geos).
- provide class names for your td tags and use CSS to specify the width. Both percentage and absolute values should work